# Excel function for comparing columns with repeated values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm using excel and have two columns (A & B) with values

I want to search for each value in Column A and return the position in Column B.
I'm using this formula:

```
IFERROR(MATCH("Values in Column A";"Array = Column B";0);0)
```

The results are:

```
Column A  | Column B  | Column C
  1       |   4       |   2
  2       |   1       |   3
  3       |   2       |   4
  4       |   1       |   1
  1       |   2       |   2
          |   3       |
```

It works fine if it doesn't encounter repeated values. However, I want it to encounter repeated values, so the formula should ignore the ones it was encountered before and go through the others. So the correct result should look like this:

```
Column C  
  2  
  3  
  5  
  1  
  4
```

Can you help me on this? Is there a VBA routine for this?

Comment: So if the number on the first list has already been searched for on the second, then search the second list, but ignore the first occurrence? What if the number is only repeated in one of the columns?

Comment: If it encounters a value that is only repeated in one of the columns, the formula returns value "0", that's why i'm using the IFERROR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article [Getting the 2nd matching value from a list using VLOOKUP formula](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/11/10/vlookup-second-value/),  you can create a helper column to affix the instance number of each value, to create unique id's.

For example, in Column C, add the following function:

```
=A1&"-"&COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)
```

> **Note**: The relative reference on the count range will cause the applicable range to grow as it is dragged down.  The count of the items matching that cell in a range containing only that cell should always be one.  As it gets dragged down to include other cells, it will increment accordingly.

Then add the same thing in Column D to get the instances of cells in Column B:

```
=B1&"-"&COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B1)
```

Finally, do the math you want to do in Column E like this:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(C1,D:D,0),0)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Oh. Your E is +1 from the answer, I think it's giving row number instead of list position

Comment: @Raystafarian, Yeah, easy to fix, don't match on `D:D`, but on `D2:D99`.  Right now the item in the first position of the match array is the column header.  But this is still the right vehicle for that.